# How to get CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback to persist even if app is in background/exit

Tags: android, android-service, android-camera2

I am trying to detect camera openings/availability based on shared preference in Android API 21+.

Basically, the flow of the program would work as such:

User open app, set whether they would like app to track/detect camera usage. 
Setting will be saved as a shared preferences.

Than base on this shared preferences, I would register for camera availability.

But I would like the callback for the camera availability to persist even after app close/exit/reboot.

Until the user change the setting.

Up till now, I have only been able to register the callback in my activity, which works fine as long as the app is in the foreground.

I was planning to use foreground service to register the callback but thought that it might not be the optimal solution.

Besides using foreground services, could there be a better solution?

Reasons for EDIT:
Added target version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Background camera tracking does not work in Android P and onwards (security reasons)
2. Without a foreground service your minimized app can be killed at any time, so even if it was possible, it wouldn't last long

So I guess using a foreground service is the only option